# graphql mongoose returning null

Tags: express, mongoose, graphql, apollo-server, express-graphql

I am using graphql with express and mongoose. for some reasons, I am getting `null` value for embedded documents. tried both async/await and promise.

Schema.JS

```
const typeDefs = `
type Patient{
    name:String
}

type Order {
    _id: ID!
    orderName: String!
    orderDate: Int,
    patient:Patient
}

type Query {
    allOrders: [Order]
}

`;
module.exports.schema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers
});
```

resolver.JS

```
module.exports.resolvers = {
    Query: {
        async allOrders() {
            return await db.cpoeDataModel.CpoeOrder.find();
        }
    },
    Order: {
        patient: async (order) => {
            console.log("patient Id##", order.patientId);
            return await db.domainModel.Patient.findById(order.patientId);
        }

    }
};
```

the query:

```
{
  allOrders {
    orderName,
    patient {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

result:

```
 {
    "allOrders": [
      {
        "orderName": "order1",
        "patient": null
      },
      {
        "orderName": "order2",
        "patient": null
      }]
}
```

expected result

```
{
                "allOrders": [
                  {
                    "orderName": "order1",
                    "patient": {
                     "name":"xyz"
                   }
                  },
                  {
                    "orderName": "order2",
                    "patient": {
                     "name":"xyz"
                   }
                  }]
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with my order collection not with code. there was some reference of patient Ids that does not exist anymore. that's why getting null values that are acceptable. I was confused just bcoz it's on the top of results.